# DVD-ROM/optical drive begins to read disc when browsing or saving files

Tags: performance

This has bothered me for some time now.

When downloading a file from the internet, the browser/save file window gets stuck for about 3 seconds because the optical drive is loading like crazy. Besides, it's really noisy so I don't want my optical drive to do anything unless necessary.

This also happens sometimes while browsing my secondary hard disk drive.

Is there a way disable this behaviour? Why is it necessary for the optical drive to do anything at all when I'm not even using it?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

Take the disc out of the drive if you do not need it.

**Long answer**

Windows needs to make the data from the disc readily available when you have the dialog box open because apparently it does not remember if a disc is in there or not and whether or not it already scanned it.